# Can't find table in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an oracle query `SELECT * FROM My_Table` which returns rows as expected.

I am trying to get information on some of the columns in the table however when I query All_Tab_Columns there are no columns where `TABLE_NAME = 'My_Table'`

I then queried ALL_TABLES and ALL_VIEWS but I couldn't find a table/view where `TABLE_NAME = 'My_Table'` or where `VIEW_NAME = 'My_Table'`.

What am i missing here? What else could My_Table be and how can I find information on the columns that are being returned when I query it?

Comment: table names are in uppcase.

Comment: Use `all_objects`.  The object in question could, for example, be a synonym.  By default, Oracle identifiers are case-insensitive but are stored in upper case in the dictionary.  If you are searching for a mixed case table name, that would only work if you were using case-sensitive (double-quoted) identifiers for your object names.

Comment: @JustinCave - Thanks that did it. It is indeed a synonym.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Oracle syntax is not case sensitive, but data is case sensitive.
so you can query your table as following:

```
select * from all_tables where table_name like upper('%My_Table%')
```

if you did not find any data about table this could be synonym
so you can query about it from all_synonyms view.

```
select * from all_synonyms where synonym_name like upper('%My_Table%')
```

Comment: Thanks. Like JustinCave's comment on the original post suggested i needed to query all_objects table. Since his was a comment and yours is an answer i'll mark yours as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, tables names (and all object names for that matter) are actually upper-cased internally by default.  If you query the data dictionary using this `WHERE` clause, you should get results:

```
where TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE'
```

Comment: I tried that already and i still didn't get anything. I even queried all of ALL_TABLES and ALL_VIEWS and ordered them by TABLE_NAME and VIEW_NAME and couldn't find 'MY_TABLE'

Comment: Looks at Justin Cave's comment.  It may not be a table or view then.  Try `all_objects` as he suggests.